# If I use my personal machine as a web server am I putting my local data at risk?

Tags: python, django, macos, security

I am considering purchasing an imac with the thought of dual-purposing the machine. I'd like to use it as a home computer, but also host a personal website or two using OSX Server.

By using my computer as a server, is there any way that a malicious attack through my website can allow someone access to files that are stored locally on my hard drive? Is it safer to simply use a dedicated machine or service?

NB: I hope that a question regarding website security is appropriate, sorry that this isn't explicitly a coding question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course it's absolutely possible. Depending on the services you are running, you will always be adding more potential holes for an attacker to find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes plus it won't save you much time / money. Proper hosting isn't that expensive. What about the DNS, you're going to point to your own Internet Connection IP address, can you guarantee it won't change or stop working at any time?

> Is it safer to simply use a dedicated machine or service?

Go with a service that handles everything for you unless you enjoy system admin stuffs.